# WPF Binding: Throttle the binding list's updates

Tags: wpf, data-binding, .net-4.0, system.reactive, xamdatagrid

I am binding the xamdatagrid to a list.But since there are too many updates on the list GUI get stuck.How can I stop these updates and refresh the grid after an interval(say 500 ms).Will Reactive extension's throttle method be useful?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`DeferRefresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.deferrefresh.aspx) to defer the binding update until you're done making modifications to the collection:

```
using (collection.DeferRefresh())
{
    // Make changes to the collection
    ...
}
```

If the collection is being updated in real time, you could use a timer to update the binding at intervals:

```
private IDisposable _deferral;
private void refreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_deferral != null)
        _deferral.Dispose();

    _deferral = collection.DeferRefresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah collection is being updated at real time so 
 according to your answer how should I use refreshTimer_Tick(...)?

Comment: @vkg, yes. Not sure it's the best option in this case, though... try it and see how it works ;)

Comment: I could not figure out how refreshTimer_Tick(...) should be used to update binding after an interval?

Comment: @vkg, just create a timer and subscribe to the Tick event with this method

Comment: Really good implementation walkthrough: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Jul/02/Debouncing-and-Throttling-Dispatcher-Events